# Python program ends abruptly and I can't decipher errors

Tags: python, mysql

```
import xlsxwriter
import MySQLdb as mdb
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('Cp1252')

first = "jim"
last = "bob"

# Initiate MySQL connection.
con = mdb.connect(unix_socket = '/var/lib/mysqld/mysqld.sock', host = 'localhost', user = 'timmy', passwd = '123America', db = 'southend');
cur = con.cursor()

query = "SELECT user_id from users where first like %s and last like %s"
# Execute MySQL query.
cur.execute(query,("%" + first + "%", "%" + last + "%"))

# Gather query results.
rows = cur.fetchall()

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('like_test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Add headers for our worksheet data.
worksheet.write('A1','User ID')

# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 1
col = 0

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for user_id in (rows):
    worksheet.write(row, col,     user_id)
    row += 1

workbook.close()

con.close()
```

Here are the errors that I get when running the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 35, in <module>
    worksheet.write(row, col,     user_id)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py", line 64, in cell_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py", line 431, in write
    raise TypeError("Unsupported type %s in write()" % type(token))
TypeError: Unsupported type <type 'tuple'> in write()
Exception Exception: Exception('Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.',) in <bound method Workbook.__del__ of <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x1a37e90>> ignored
```

I'm not really familiar with python - I'm mostly just beginning stages and they way MySQL gets called is unusual to me. Any assistance?

Since I'm using variables, I guess that I'm forced to use the '%s' options in the script.

Comment: Have you examined the types of your values yet?

Comment: It looks like user_id is a tuple rather than an int or string.

Comment: One thing that you'll find with python is that it's pretty specific about where the error happened.  You'll notice that it gives you a full trace back to your program.

Comment: user_id on the database is a varchar. Aside from that I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cur.fetchall()` returns a list of column values for each row.

Even though you are only fetching one column value, it still returns a list for each row.. with one value in it, for each row.

So:

```
for row in rows:
    worksheet.write(row, col, row[0])
```

`rows` is a list of rows, and each `row` is a list of values for that row.

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps me.

Comment: Ahh, nevermind -- I see what I needed to do. change it from row[0] to user_id[0] and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Very simple.. you are looping over `rows` to get `user_id` but rows is NOT a list of user_id's, it is a list of LISTS of values, and the first value on each list is the user_id you are looking for.  row[0] gets you the first value on the list.

Comment: I changed where you used the variable name `user_id` to `row` to reflect the reality that the variable actually is the data for a row, not a user_id.  It CONTAINS the user_id.  If you had more columns in your SELECT statement they would also be present in row.

Comment: Issue was because this was first time i was only receivng a column. In the past it has worked if I did for a,b,c in rows: etc., etc.

Comment: Note, you can also use `worksheet.write_row(row, col, row)` which will write out all the values, even if there is only one, for the list.